# Jenkins Artifactory uploadSpec replacing variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, artifactory

I am running a pipeline which builds a gradle project and its subprojects.

As I want to upload the upload spec, it only replaced the regex placeholders, but not my own variables.

Jenkinsfile is working properly, its just not uploading the artifacts with the right name.

UploadSpec:

```
def uploadSpec = '''{\
    "files": [
      {
        "pattern": "(.*)[/]build[/]libs[/].*[.]jar",
        "target": "space/team/dotspace/{1}/${projectVersion}/{1}-${projectVersion}.jar",
        "regexp": "true"
      }
   ]
  }'''
```

And yes, the def for `projectVersion` is set correctly, as I echo `§{projectVersion}` afterwords.

Output:

```
[consumer_0] Deploying artifact: http://host/artifactory/space/team/dotspace/core-game/%24%7BprojectVersion%7D/core-game-%24%7BprojectVersion%7D.jar
[consumer_1] Deploying artifact: http://host/artifactory/space/team/dotspace/core-profile/%24%7BprojectVersion%7D/core-profile-%24%7BprojectVersion%7D.jar
```

Does anyone have ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Jenkins and you are parameterizing the project, you can simply add these parameters "projectVersion" in the Jenkins configurable script. Kindly refer to this [article](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/parameterized+build) on Jenkins parameterized build.
The below screenshot if from my working example where I pass the parameter "Credentials" to the Job, and pass on the parameter "Credentials" to a variable "CREDENTIALS" in the Jenkins Script and use that variable to replace the variable with its value.
[image]

Comment: This would work, but I define the variable in my pipeline script as following:
``def projectVersion = sh(script: "gradle -q getVersion -b build.gradle", returnStdout: true)``. I do not have a default value to expect

Comment: Ok, I doubt the issue due to the target path being in double-quotes "target": "space/team/dotspace/{1}/${projectVersion}/{1}-${projectVersion}.jar", have a different variable set up and perform a concatenation and pass it on to the "target". Something like testvariable="space/team/dotspace/"+"${1}"+"${projectVersion}"+"/${1}-"+"${projectVersion}"+".jar" and pass as "target": ${testvariable}